# 2010 Mitsubishi sent up with the car just idling. The compressor isn't working because belt isn't turning & sparks & smokes a little when cranked

Tags: clutch, relay, compressor, serpentine-belt, clutch-plate

The compressor isn't working because the belt isn't turning causing it to spark and smoke a little bit when I crank it. That's without the AC or heat being on. Also, when I drive it it makes the loud squealing noise until I accelerate up to a good little steady speed then it quiets down to light squeak until I slow down again. When I get ready to stop sometimes it just does on it own. So what could be the problem?

---

Update from OP:

2010 Mitsubishi Galant SE making horrible squealing noise and the RPM's go up while just idling is what I meant!!!

Comment: Hi Tina! Welcome to our community.  I added your update to your question, but I can't quite figure out the "sent up" means in the title.  Are you able to edit it?